# Achieving rotation of logs based on size and time for the same log file using log4j.xml

Tags: log4j

Tried following to achieve rotation based on size as well as time within the same configuration applicable to a single log file

http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/log4j-user@logging.apache.org/2008-07/msg00355.html
 but the rotation based on size is not happening.Tried setting the size to 3KB. Could you please let me know if i have to correct anything.

Comment: What's your configuration?

Comment: The same configuration as mentioned in 

http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/log4j-user@logging.apache.org/2008-07/msg00355.html